# Sending iOS app to background causes delay in entire app

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance, timer

I have an app that uses a timer that runs an "update" function every .01 seconds. The function analyzes ambient soundand performs an action when it hears certain tones it is listening for.

The app works perfectly, until I send it into the background (i.e. tap the home button, or double tap).

When I re-open the app, it works the exact same, except with about a 1-2 second delay. I have my app printing out a message in the logs when it hears the sound it's listening for, and it still always hears it, it doesn't print for about a two second delay.

Things I've observed:

1. The timer still runs normally and everything seems to work perfectly, it's as if there is a delay between the hardware of what the phone is experiencing, and the actual app is running.
2. CPU stays between 40-50 percent both before and after I send it to background mode.

My app is very time sensitive so this is a deal breaker if it is even half a second delayed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with the AudioKit framework I was using. Whenever you leave the app, you have to run `try? AudioKit.stop()` and then when you come back you can `try AudioKit.start()` again, otherwise all the audio stuff is delayed.